# How to create an AVD from a user-created device definition in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I would like to create an AVD from a device definition I created to test my app in tough conditions.

I created a device definition by going to `Android Virtual Device Manager -> Device Definitions -> New Device`.

However, In the same `Android Virtual Device Manager` window, when I click on `Create AVD...` button, my created device definition won't appear there.
Also, when I exit the `Android Virtual Device Manager` window, and open it again, my created definition seems to be gone completely.

Is there an option to create an AVD from a user-created device definition?

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to create a new defenition.

> avd manager->device def tab -> new device

Enter the device spec and click `create device.`

Comment: that's what I did, but then when I click on `Create AVD...` in the `Device Definitions` tab or `New` in the `Android Virtual Devices` tab, it won't appear there. It seems like it doesn't save it even though it shows in the `Device` list in the `Device Definitions` tab. When I close the `Android Virtual Device Manager` window and reopen it, the definition I created disappears from this list as well.

Comment: I think you can save time by installing it again. :)